# Presenting modal on tabs using React Native and Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo-router

I have an app with four tabs I want to be able to present a modal screen on any of the tab items. I'm trying to get my head around expo-router, however, it's not going through.

My file structure is:

```
app
    (auth)
        _layout.js
        Onboard.js
        SignIn.js
        ForgotPassword.js
    (tabs)
        _layout.js
        Home1.js
        Home2.js
        Home3.js
        Home4.js
_layout.js
index.js
```

Do I need a new group with:

```
_layout.js
Modal.js
```

and does this go under my (tabs) folder of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Add your-modal.js to your (tabs) folder. Then in (tabs)/_layout.js add a Tab-screen with name='your-modal' and options={{href:null}}.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by adding Modal screen what ever tab you want. like use stack-navigation inside tabs.

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/ please review here you can find example too.